# How to bind a module in system verilog, with parameters not from the target location

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I would like to bind a module, and pass a parameter from the module I declared the bind in, rather than them all coming from the module I am binding *to*.

```
module dut(input logic A, output logic B);
  assign B = A;
endmodule

module dut_verif_bind#(
  string IF_PATH = "a_string"
) (
  inout A,
  input B
);
  import uvm_pkg::*;

  AB_intf vif();
  assign vif.A = A;
  assign vif.B = B;
  initial begin
    uvm_config_db#(virtual AB_intf)::set(null, IF_PATH, "vif", vif);
  end
endmodule
```

The bind module would be bound from some higher level (a testbench, or another bind module) to `dut`. The fact that this can be another bind module is why I want to be able to bind the parameters like this.

```
module tb#(string IF_PATH = "uvm_test_top*") ();
  dut my_dut();
  bind my_dut dut_verif_bind#(.IF_PATH($sformatf("%s.dut*", IF_PATH))) dut_if_binds (.*);
endmodule
```

The above however, gives errors, because in the parameter binding of the bind module (`#(.IF_PATH($sformatf("%s.dut*", IF_PATH)))`) it is searching for the IF_PATH parameter in the module being bound *to*, not in the scope of the bind declaration. This is somewhat intuitive, though I hadn't considered that issue, but it also seems like there should be a way around it.

For those wondering, this structure is something I am exploring because it should wind up making mid-level testbenches and tests nearly trivial to run if you have a unit and system test anyways. Just need a couple extra sequences and a couple more agent instantiations, but you don't have to start over with declaring interfaces and tossing them in the database, and shouldn't have to move them around the database at all.

How to bind a module in system verilog, with parameters not from the target location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the use of parameters to places that require constant expressions. In this case, there is no need to make IF_PATH a `parameter`; it can be a `string` variable.

```
module dut_verif_bind (
  inout A,
  input B
);
  string IF_PATH;
  import uvm_pkg::*;

  AB_intf vif();
  assign vif.A = A;
  assign vif.B = B;
  initial begin
    wait(IF_PATH !="")
    uvm_config_db#(virtual AB_intf)::set(null, IF_PATH, "vif", vif);
  end
endmodule
module tb#(string IF_PATH = "uvm_test_top*") ();
  dut my_dut();
  bind my_dut dut_verif_bind dut_if_binds (.*);
 initial
    my_dut.dut_verif_bind.IF_PATH = $sformatf("%s.dut*", IF_PATH);
endmodule
```